# How do you make the salutation on Person Accounts mandatory?

Tags: person-accounts

I tried this using the validation rule:
ISPICKVAL(Salutation, "")
but this then also applies to the standard Account object. I just need this for Person Accounts so can this be restricted even more?

Answer (score 2):

There should be a boolean field IsPersonAccount which can be used to check if the current record is a person account or not.

Comment: i.e. `IsPersonAccount && ISPICKVAL(Salutation, '')`.